# A discrete normal subgroup is contained in the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $N$ a discrete normal subgroup of $G$. Then $N$ is contained in the center $Z(G)$.

I've fooled around with this for a little bit and I can't figure out how to use the hypothesis that $N$ is discrete. I think maybe it uses some fact that I do not know.

Comment: Re: your initially-missing "connectedness" hypothesis: It's worth remembering that every finite group is a Lie Group (0-dimensional, discrete topology), so when you come to prove a fact like this, and you notice it's not true for finite groups, then surely connectedness will come into play!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $n$ be an element of the subgroup. Then the function $f:G\to N$ sending $g\mapsto gng^{-1}$ is continuous, and since $G$ is connected, so is the image of $f$. Since $N$ is discrete, $f(g) =n$ for all $g$.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to say $G$ was connected. That's one of my permanent assumptions.

Comment: @Tuo I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: Why does $N$ beign discrete impliy $gng^{-1}=n$?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa The only connected subsets of a discrete space are singletons, and the image of $G$ is connected and contains $n$.

Comment: Sorry but could you explain more on why the function *f* is continuous?

Comment: @HetongXu It's a composition of continuous functions.