# Quotient space of sphere $S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$ as a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology

Is there a way to prove or understand whether a quotient space of sphere
$$S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$$ is a Lie group or not? from some $n$ and $k$.

It seems to me that the only possible Lie groups from the empirical laws telling me that only
$S^1=U(1)$, $S^1/(\mathbf{Z}/k)=U(1)$, and $S^3=SU(2)$ and $S^3/(\mathbf{Z}/2)=SO(3)$ can be Lie groups. But I would like to know some general arguments why is that so - or how can $S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$ can be a Lie group?

p.s. After posting the question, I noticed a helpful input from [Is there an easy way to show which spheres can be Lie groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12453/955245) - which we may generalize the statement from there.

Comment: A universal covering of a lie group has a lie group structure ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713248/lie-group-and-universal-covering-groups)). Thus $n$ is $1$ or $3$.

Comment: thanks indeed, the key word should be Lie Group from Universal Covering Groups - nice input~ +1

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you should accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Your question is answered by the following MSE posts:

- First, if $S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$ has a Lie group structure, then so is $\mathbb S^n$, the universal cover of $S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/713248/lie-group-and-universal-covering-groups)). Thus $n=1$ or $3$ from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12453/is-there-an-easy-way-to-show-which-spheres-can-be-lie-groups).
- Since $\mathbb S^n \to S^n/(\mathbf{Z}/k)$ is a group homomorphism, $\mathbf Z/k$ is a normal subgroup of $\mathbb S^n$. From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3089905/a-discrete-normal-subgroup-is-contained-in-the-center), it must lies in the center. When $n=3$, the center of $SU(2)$ is $\{ \pm I\}$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686557/how-to-compute-the-center-of-su2)), so $SU(2)$ and $SO(3)$ are the only options. For $n=1$, you listed already all the options.